# Pandas dataframe resample without aggregation

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe defined as follows:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

todays_date = datetime.datetime.today().date()
index = pd.date_range(todays_date - datetime.timedelta(10), periods=10, freq='D')
index = index.append(index)
idname = ['A']*10 + ['B']*10
values = random.sample(xrange(100), 20)
data = np.vstack((idname, values)).T

tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'value'])
tmp_index = pd.DataFrame(index, columns=['date'])
tmp_df = pd.concat([tmp_index, tmp_df], axis=1)
tmp_df = tmp_df.set_index('date')
```

Note that there are 2 values for each date.  I would like to resample the dataframe `tmp_df` on a weekly basis but keep the two separate values.  I tried `tmp_df.resample('W-FRI')` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is your desired output? And what error do you get?

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you're looking for is `groupby`, which lets you perform operations on dataframe slices (here 'A' and 'B') independently:

```
df.groupby('id').resample('W-FRI')
```

Note: your code produces an error (`No numeric types to aggregate`) because the `'value'` column is not converted to `int`. You need to convert it first:

```
df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'])
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  I wasn't aware of doing it via groupby() and so learned something new.  I was going to resort to pivoting it to have the columns by the different id values, which wouldn't have achieved the same result as the question.